# How to get web pages from Asst Folder in to View Pager?

Tags: android

I have list of web pages in asset folder.I am trying to create an PagerAdapter, where I can change the web pages on swipes. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Try this to read data:

```
BufferedReader reader = null;
try {
    reader = new BufferedReader(
        new InputStreamReader(getAssets().open("filename.txt")));

    // read line 
    String mLine;
    while ((mLine = reader.readLine()) != null) {
       //process line
       ...
    }
} catch (IOException e) {
    //exception
} finally {
    if (reader != null) {
         try {
             reader.close();
         } catch (IOException e) {
             //exception
         }
    }
}
```

Comment: thanks Bruno, really appreciate your help.It worked,